# How do you change css when window size gets to a certain point in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the font to adjust when the sc reen size gets to 1050px. How do i do this with javascript

Comment: No need to do that in javascript, take a look at [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `css`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
    body {
        /* set font adjusters here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css and javascript

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
    body {
       font-size: // the value you want
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
if(screen.width < your point) {
  // change font size
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add event listener

```
const handleResize = () => {
  if(window.innerHeight > 1050) {
     //you can change font size here
     document.getElementById("yourelement").style.fontSize = "69px";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
```